# How can send parameter by a tag in django?

Tags: django, parameters

I have a 'a tag' such like this.

```
<a href="{% 'mains:index' %}" name="getData">button</a>
```

If I click this button, i want to send parameter name "getData"
like below, but it does not work.

## views.py

```
def index(request):
  result = request.GET.get('getData')
```

how can I get prameter from template by a tag, and how can using in views.py?
      return = render(request, 'mains/index.html', 'result':result)

if my question is confused, just ask me plz.

Comment: read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use builtin `url` for this. `<a href="{% url 'index' %}?getData=True">button</a>` should work. But I highly recommend you to use forms to send data from html to view with an elegant format as Hisham___Pak mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Good news, Can you accept the answer to help others to see the answer easily?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

put url.py file view like add name = 'index'

{% url 'index' %}" name="getData"

Comment: I can't understand
Is it matter name argument?

path('index/', views.index, name="index"),

I already write like above

Comment: another answer really help for me. Sorry about my explanation and thank you for your help, either.